# Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero

Tags: r, if-statement, shinydashboard

the code works perfectly until I select radio buttons (to filter the data by different values, be it by country/office/customer/etc..) 
i get this error:

[image: Warning:Error screenshot]

and here are the mentioned lines of code that contains this error:

```
  output$levelQueryUi <- renderUI({
    radioButtons("analysisLevel", label = "Level of Analysis",
                 choices = list("Office Country" = 1, "Office" = 2, "Market" = 3, "Source Market"  = 4, "Customer" =5), 
                 selected = 1)
  })
    officedata <- reactive({

       #office country Radio Button id selescted
       if(input$analysisLevel == 1)
       {
       subset(
         ct,
       ct$`Office Country` %in%  input$officecountry
       )
       }
       # office Radio Button id selescted
       else if(input$analysisLevel == 2)
         {
           subset(
             ct,
             ct$Office %in%  input$office
           )
         }
         else if(input$analysisLevel == 3)
           {
         subset(
           ct,
           ct$Market %in%  input$market
         )
         }
       else if(input$analysisLevel == 4)
       {
         subset(
           ct,
           ct$`Source Market` %in%  input$sourcemarket
         )
       }
       else if(input$analysisLevel == 5)
       {
         subset(
           ct,
           ct$Customer %in%  input$customer
         )
       }
       else{
         return(ct)
       }
     })

     #filtered data
     filteredcancelled <- reactive({
       subset(
         officedata(),
         officedata()$Status %in% "Cancelled"
       )
     })

     #Average Project Size
     officedataconcom <- reactive({ 
       subset(
         officedata(),
         officedata()$Start >= "2018-01-01" &
           officedata()$Status == "Completed" |
           officedata()$Status == "Confirmed"
       )
     })

     ##############################DATA BY OFFICE OFFICE COUNTRY MARKET SOURCE MARKET AND CUSTOMER###########################
     output$numofenqby <- renderValueBox({
       valueBox(nrow(officedata()), "Number of Enquiries", color = "blue", icon = icon("star"))

     })
```

i reviewed them to try to catch what is the error, but I couldn't, and I also tried to review similar questions in stack**overflow** before posting this question, but with no vain.

and a very important thing is that my code still works, even with this warning. it is just a warning, but i prefer to get rid of it.

this is the output that when i click different options it gives me the mentioned above errors: 
[image: Filtering data]
so my console stays clean until i try to shuffle between those different buttons (Office Country/Office/Market/Source Market/Customer), and when i do, I get those Warning..

**the UI code related to the radio buttons**

```
  tabItem(tabName = "explorer",
                                    fluidPage(
                                      title = "Market Explorer",
                                      column(width = 3,
                                             box(
                                               title = "Query Builder",
                                               status = "primary",
                                               width = 12,
                                               solidHeader = TRUE,
                                               background = "navy",
                                               box(
                                                 width = 12,
                                                 status = "primary",
                                                 solidHeader = FALSE,
                                                 background = "navy",
                                                 uiOutput("levelQueryUi")
                                               ),# end of box
                                               conditionalPanel(
                                                 condition = "input.analysisLevel == 1",
                                                 box(
                                                   status = "primary",
                                                   solidHeader = FALSE,
                                                   width = 12,
                                                   background = "navy",
                                                   uiOutput("officecountryUi")
                                                 )# end of box
                                               ),# end of conditional panel 
                                               conditionalPanel(
                                                 condition = "input.analysisLevel == 2",
                                                 box(
                                                   status = "primary",
                                                   solidHeader = FALSE,
                                                   width = 12,
                                                   background = "navy",
                                                   uiOutput("officeUi")
                                                 )# end of box
                                               ),# end of conditional panel  
                                               conditionalPanel(
                                                 condition = "input.analysisLevel == 3",
                                                 box(
                                                   status = "primary",
                                                   solidHeader = FALSE,
                                                   width = 12,
                                                   background = "navy",
                                                   uiOutput("marketUi")
                                                 )# end of box
                                               ),# end of conditionalpanel    
                                               conditionalPanel(
                                                 condition = "input.analysisLevel == 4",
                                                 box(
                                                   status = "primary",
                                                   solidHeader = FALSE,
                                                   width = 12,
                                                   background = "navy",
                                                   uiOutput("sourcemarketUi")
                                                )#end of box
                                               ),# end of conditionalpanel
                                               conditionalPanel(
                                                 condition = "input.analysisLevel == 5",
                                                 box(
                                                   status = "primary",
                                                   solidHeader = FALSE,
                                                   width = 12,
                                                   background = "navy",
                                                   uiOutput("customerUi")
                                                 )#end of box
                                               ),# end of conditionalpanel
                                                box(
                                                 status = "primary",
                                                 solidHeader = FALSE,
                                                 width = 12,
                                                 background = "navy",
                                                 sliderInput("hviQuery", label = "Project Value Range ($000)", min = 0, max = 2000, value = c(0,1000)),
                                                 checkboxInput("maxValue", label = "Include all values exceeding $2m", value = FALSE)
                                               ), # end of box
                                               box(
                                                 status = "primary",
                                                 solidHeader = FALSE,
                                                 width = 12,
                                                 background = "navy",
                                                 selectInput("horizon", label = "Time Horizon:", 
                                                             choices = c("Monthly", "Quarterly", "Annual", "5 Year", "10 Year"),
                                                             selected = "Annual",
                                                             selectize = FALSE)
                                               ),# end of box
                                               actionButton("query", label = "Go") 
                                             )# end of box
                                      ),# end of column
                                      # conditionalPanel(
                                      #   condition = "input.query",
                                        column(width = 9,
                                               box(
                                                 title = "Market Data",
                                                 status = "primary",
                                                 width = 12,
                                                 solidHeader = TRUE,
                                                 collapsible = TRUE,
                                                 fluidRow(
                                                   valueBoxOutput("numofenqby", width = 4),
                                                   valueBoxOutput("averageprojectsize", width = 4),
                                                   valueBoxOutput("Materialisationrate", width = 4),
                                                   valueBoxOutput("cancelledworkvalueby", width = 4),
                                                   valueBoxOutput("averageGOPby", width = 4),
                                                   valueBoxOutput("confirmedasperby", width = 4),
                                                   valueBoxOutput("pastrequestsby", width = 4),
                                                   valueBoxOutput("ofcorporateby", width = 4),
                                                   valueBoxOutput("ofagencyby", width = 4))))))
```

Any help please? I would be really thankful

Comment: Can you post the UI code related to the radio buttons? I'm confused about the difference between the `input$analysisLevel` and the individual `input`s for market, office, etc. I would also recommend using `print` to your benefit. Potentially put a print command in this reactive to print the value of your input so you can easily debug.

Comment: Can you provide me a reproduceable example? At least the radiobuttons?

Comment: yes sure
i will edit the post and add it on, not in a comment

Comment: I've edited the post Thanks

Comment: @rfortin hey.. ? any luck ?

Comment: @JanaZuraik apologies, just seeing this now. It's hard to debug interactive code like this, especially because you're code is incredibly nested and conditional. It's also hard to say if the error is being thrown by your if statements or your subsetting by dropdowns. First, I would recommend inserting prints into your if statements to see what's actually breaking. For example, add `print(input$analysisLevel)` above all if statements, and then add `print(input$officeCountry)` or whichever respective dropdown is needed in each if or else if statement. Then check your console every time you change

Comment: @JanaZuraik Second, I would recommend restructuring your code. Is it necessary to have your radio buttons defined in the server instead of the UI? Do you need to have separate uiOutput's for each potential radiobutton selection, or could you define one set of `selectInput` and then use `updateSelectInput` to change the options and text when the radio buttons change? This would make it much more easy to read, and then the massive officeData reactive just becomes a single if statement. This would make it much more easy to read and debug.

Comment: @JanaZuraik Finally, I would look into using the `futile.logger` package. This would be an enhanced way of using the `print` command and can be a massive help to debugging. At each possible place a user can take an action like an input that affects the server code, add a `flog.info(paste("User just changed analysisLevel radioButton to", input$analysisLevel))`. This will appear in the console and can help keep track of what's breaking.

Comment: @rfortin thank you very much ! so rich information and directions... i will work accordingly
I will update the answer here after i debug and figure out where the bug was! thank you